# What "source code files" are needed to turnover (continue develop of) an iOS application?

Tags: ios, xcode, ipa

I am working with a developer on an iOS app and upon completion, all source code, files, etc. should be turned over to me so that I can continue development in the future with another developer if necessary. I need help understanding exactly which files I should receive.

Should I be ok with .ipa file? Or maybe .app file? Or the Xcode project file? What will ensure that I have all I need to continue development in the future?

Comment: Pretty much everything inside the project folder. Just use GitHub or something. And commit the project to it. Then you don't need to worry.

Comment: I imagine you would take ownership of *everything* created by the developer as part of the contract.  On a technical level, everything needed to create the application should be in source control.  And if you own the application then you should own the source control repository.  One of the developer's deliverables should be to provide you with the process for building and deploying the application.

Comment: Source code is .. source. IPA/APP (packaged executable) files are *compiled*; and *not* source. The Xcode project file is indeed a start; but all the other *source* files (eg. ".m", and relevant assets) that are referenced also need to be included. Basically, the developer should provide *all* the [source] files that are *required to build* the application from Xcode.

Comment: If you can open the project in XCode, build it, and run it on your device, you're good.

Answer (score 1):

You will receive the project folder, which contains a `.xcodeproj` file and other files such as images assets. You can download a demo project from [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/x7avclri0ijw3pd/DemoConstraints.zip?dl=0).

You won't receive an `.ipa` file because the `.ipa` files are the ones you download from the App Store (they have been archived), hence no one can see their code so people can't steal it.

Comment: http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/1594/possibilities-for-reverse-engineering-an-ipa-file-to-its-source